# Could not execute the java executable while running Play 1.2.1

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, java, path

I am facing this issue whenever I am trying to run Play 1.2.1 in my system. Previously, I had Play 2.0 in my system. I exported the `$PATH` variable so that `$PATH` contains the path to Play 2.0 directory.

Now, I am trying to run Play 1.2.1 in Mac OS X 10.7.4.

My PATH variable looks like:

```
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/sabya/Documents/Play_Framework/play-2.0: No such file or directory
```

After exporting the `$PATH` for play 1.2.1 my `$PATH` looks like:

```
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/sabya/Documents/Play_Framework/play-2.0:/Users/sabya/Downloads/Work/play-1.2.1: No such file or directory
```

I created a new project through `play new test_app`. But whenever I am trying to do `play run`, it shows:

```
Could not execute the java executable, please make sure the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set properly (the java executable should reside at JAVA_HOME/bin/java).
```

Calling `javac` or `java` in the same directory gives me proper output.

Echoing `$JAVA_HOME` returns `-bash: /Library/Java/Home: No such file or directory`

Everything works fine in Ubuntu.

What is the workaround for this situation? I have Googled extensively, but I did not get anything suitable.

Is the trailing ":" in `$JAVA_HOME` a problem?

Comment: I can assure you that a trailing colon in your `$JAVA_HOME` is not the problem. As to the rest of it, could you please describe Play (what it is, what it's supposed to do, how it's supposed to work)?

Comment: Thanks CajunLuke for the comment . Play is a framework for web development. For more description visit www.playframework.org